# Facebook event subscribe comment.create response url

Tags: facebook

I use Facebook social comments plugin on my web page. I use event subscribe method to get the comments and save it to local database. Everything works perfectly well, except the response of comment link. Event subscribe code snippet:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    FB.Event.subscribe("comment.create", function(response){           
          alert(response.href);
    });
};
```

Let's say I have the Facebook comments plugin on some page which url is:

> http://mywebpage.com/index.php?article_id=10

So event subscribe returns the url which is equal to:

> http://www.facebook.com/http://mywebpage.com/index.php?article_id=10

But that url does not exist... So what's wrong with that? How to get the correct url?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the PHP urlencode function that I used for encoding the page url before passing it to the Facebook plugin. So simply removed it and things got fixed.